# Reset the equation counter

Tags: counters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, chngcntr}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{solution}

\newcommand\Problem{%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{\theproblem.}~%
  \setcounter{solution}{0}%
}

\newcommand\TheSolution{%
  \textbf{Solution:}\\%
}

\newcommand\ASolution{%
  \stepcounter{solution}%
  \textbf{Solution \thesolution:}\\%
}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}

\section{Kinematics}

\Problem A motorboat going going downstream overcame a raft at point $\emph{A}$; $\tau$ = 60 min later it turned back and after some time passed the raft at a distance $l$ = 6.0 km from the point $\emph{A}$. Find flow velocity assuming the duty of the engine to be constant.

\TheSolution Let u be the flow velocity and v be velocity of boat in still water, 
    \begin{equation} \frac{l}{u}=\tau + \frac{(u+v)\tau-l}{v-u}  \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} u=\frac{l}{2\tau}=\frac{6}{2\cdot1}=3 \ km/hr \end{equation} 

\Problem  A point traversed half the distance with a velocity $v_0$. The remaining part of the distance was covered with velocity $v_1$ for half the time, and with velocity $v_2$ for the other half of the time. Find the mean velocity of the point averaged over the whole time of motion. 

\TheSolution \begin{equation} v_{av} = \frac{2\cdot v_0\cdot\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}}{v_0 + \frac{v_1+v_2}{2}} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This is my basic template for  writing my problems and their solutions now if I compile this it will give this:

[image: Output of the abv code]

Now I want it so that the equation counter resets after each question like in que 2 it doesn't become (3) but becomes (1).

Comment: What sense will have numbering of equation which will repeating and not be unique? With this you will lost possibilities to referencing them (uniquely). Than is better to not number them at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your formatting requirements, you have two main choices for how to reset the `equation` counter automatically each time a new `problem` environment starts.,

- If you just want to reset the `equation` counter each time a new `problem` starts, but do *not* wish to change the way the equation counter is displayed as well, you could run the following instruction in the preamble:

  ```
  \counterwithin*{equation}{problem}
  ```

  Note the "star" (`*`) symbol at the end of `\counterwithin*`.
- If, in addition to resetting the `equation` counter, you wish to change the appearance of the counter so that it displays (1.1), (1.2) etc for equations associated with problem 1; {2.1) etc for equations associated with problem 2, etc, you could run the following code in the preamble:

  ```
  \counterwithin{equation}{problem}
  ```

---

The following code assumes you want to pursue the second option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{solution}

%% option 1
%\counterwithin*{equation}{problem
%% option 2
\counterwithin{equation}{problem}

\newcommand\Problem{%
  \refstepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{\theproblem.}~%
  \setcounter{solution}{0}%
}

\newcommand\TheSolution{%
  \textbf{Solution:}\\%
}

\newcommand\ASolution{%
  \stepcounter{solution}%
  \textbf{Solution \thesolution:}\\%
}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1em

\usepackage{siunitx} % for \qty and \unit macros

\begin{document}

\section{Kinematics}

\Problem 
A motorboat going downstream passed a raft at point $\emph{A}$; $\tau = \qty{60}{min}$ later it turned back and after some time passed the raft at a distance $l = \qty{6.0}{km}$ from the point $\emph{A}$. Find flow velocity assuming the duty of the engine to be constant.

\TheSolution Let $u$ be the flow velocity and $v$ be velocity of boat in still water,
    \begin{equation} \frac{l}{u}=\tau + \frac{(u+v)\tau-l}{v-u}  
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} u=\frac{l}{2\tau}=\frac{6}{2\cdot1}=\qty{3}{km/hr} \end{equation}

\Problem  
A point traversed half the distance with a velocity $v_0$. The remaining part of the distance was covered with velocity $v_1$ for half the time, and with velocity $v_2$ for the other half of the time. Find the mean velocity of the point averaged over the whole time of motion.

\TheSolution 
\begin{equation} v_{av} = \frac{2\cdot v_0\cdot\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}}{v_0 + \frac{v_1+v_2}{2}} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uh! Why not `\counterwithin*{equation}{problem}` instead of going with `\@addtoreset`?

Comment: @egreg - Mostly because I'd forgotten the "starred" variant of `\counterwithin`... Let me fix this issue right away.

Answer (score 0):

The command `\setcounter{equation}{0}` will reset the equation counter to 0. The next time you have a numbered equation, the counter will be incremented and displayed, so that this equation will have number 1.